# Can you reference a worksheets codename in an Office Add-in?

Tags: office-js

I'm working with Office Add-ins in VS and trying to get a worksheets codename. Every example I've found only uses the text name of a worksheet. Is there a way to find/use the codename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I guess you are asking for the id? You could get the worksheet.id by the following code sample

```
async function getActiveWorksheet() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    sheet.load("name");
    sheet.load("id");

    await context.sync();

    console.log("The active worksheet :" + sheet.name + " and sheet Id :" +sheet.id);
  });
}
```

The document can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=excel-js-preview#id

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you Raymond! In VBA it's called a 'codename'. Very different going from VBA to JavaScript.